# Can a Firefox extention replace "Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site?"

Tags: web, firefox, firefox-addon

The goal is to replace the page `Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.` when a host is not found on Firefox with an extension.

From the documentation, `content_scripts` only works if the URL requirements exists, it's not possible to inject JS before it

Example:

Doesn't inject the JS, only show the error page

```
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*.test/*"],
    "js": ["./static/js/content.js"],
  }
],
...
```

JS is injected

```
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*.com/*"],
    "js": ["./static/js/content.js"],
  }
],
...
```

The goal is to modify the "error" page when the host is not found to replace the content with something else